# Filtering for each Column Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to filtering my data for each json value. 
I create a applyFilterFunction : 
FilterPredicate Table by Column with Angular Material

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string, key: string) {
    let filterObj = {
      value: filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(),
      key: key
    };
    this.dataSource.filter = filterObj;
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

and my filterPredicate (ngOnInit) is :

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
      if(data[filter.key]) {
        return data[filter.key].toLowerCase().includes(filter.value);
      }
      return false;
    }
```

but its return an error :

> error TS2339: Property 'key' does not exist on type 'string'. error
>   TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'. error
>   TS2322: Type '{ value: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to
>   type 'string'.

Can you help me ?